# Insufficient String Buffer Declaration

Tags: java

I use tool to check coding style 
And I got many advise :

> StringBuffer constructor is initialized with size 16, but has at least 35 characters appended.

Here is some of my code:

```
final StringBuffer Contents = new StringBuffer();
```

WHy whould this happen?
How did it count `35 characters`?
How can I edit the size of StringBuffer ?
Or What method should I use to solve this problem??

Comment: if you know the first part at least, you can add it to the constructor, e.g., `new StringBuffer("firstPart");`, or if you expect a standard size, use the constructor that cahen suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the capacity of a `StringBuffer` after it has been created is more costly than creating it with the expected needed capacity.

Use this constructor to remove this warning:

```
    /**
     * Constructs a string buffer with no characters in it and
     * the specified initial capacity.
     *
     * @param      capacity  the initial capacity.
     * @exception  NegativeArraySizeException  if the <code>capacity</code>
     *               argument is less than <code>0</code>.
     */
    public StringBuffer(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I have a question about ````initialized with size 16````  It means at first just 16,and then it can auto-enlarge depend on my string,right?

Comment: exactly. The default constructor starts with capacity 16 but it will auto-enlarge as needed. The warning you got is just about improving the performance, your application wouldn't break because of this

Answer (score 1):

> Why whould this happen?

Do you mean, why would you get that message?

Most likely, because what it is saying is true!!  That is: the code that comes after this declaration adds at least 35 characters to the `StringBuffer`.

> How did it count 35 characters?

By counting.

It has analysed the code following the declaration, and computed the sum of the lengths of all the character and string literals that are unconditionally `append`-ed to the buffer.

> How can I edit the size of StringBuffer ?

You can create a `StringBuffer` with space for at least 35 characters as follows:

```
  new StringBuffer(35);
```

However this may not be the most appropriate solution.  What the message is alluding to is this: it is more efficient to allocate a buffer that is big enough, rather than creating it too small, and having the buffer grow it.  The buffer resizing policy for `StringBuffer` is to roughly double the required capacity when the current capacity is insufficient. So if you were to set the capacity to 35 characters but 48 were required, then the policy may well expand the buffer to 70 or 80.

In practice, if the actual amount of buffer space generally fits into a small range of value, the optimal choice of the capacity is likely to be a few characters larger than upper bound of the range.  A capacity that is just too small, or significantly too large is going to be suboptimal.

---

By the way, unless the buffer is shared by multiple threads, it would be better to use a `StringBuilder` rather than a `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

From [`docs of StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer(int))

> At any point in time it contains some particular sequence of characters, but the length and content of the sequence can be changed through certain method calls.

If you know the length before in hand, use [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer(int)) to specify the length. If you want to increase your buffer you can do at any point of time.

```
 contents.setLength(i);
```

*As a side note, variable names starts with lower-case letters. Changed `Contents` to `contents`.*