# Insufficient String Buffer Declaration

Tags: java

StringBuffer constructor is initialized with size 51, but has at least 584 characters appended.

I am getting the above Error. for this code

```
StringBuilder de = new StringBuilder("=================================\n"); de.append("Selection from Final Module List\n"); 
de.append("=================================\n"); 
for (String d : moduleFilterColumnsWithModuleNameAndAddress) { 
    de.append(d).append(" $ "); 
} 
de.append("\n"); 
de.append("-------------------------------------------------‌​--------------------‌​---------------\n");
```

I could not use following constructor because i could not find the maximum size of the string that i am going to append

> new StringBuilder(51);

Please help me to solve the sonar issue for the above code.

[image]

Please find screenshot to see the error

Comment: Can you paste your actual code? Also consider using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Your error is very strange, and sounds unrelated to the size of the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31720833/5395773

Comment: Your question is not understandable, Please mention clearly what exactly you want to ask.

Comment: how are you assigning a value to StringBuffer? You can you default constructor. It will dynamically increase the size as you want.

Comment: This is my code  StringBuilder de = new StringBuilder("=================================\n");
        de.append("Selection from Final Module List\n");
        de .append("=================================\n");

        for (String d : moduleFilterColumnsWithModuleNameAndAddress) {
            de .append(d).append(" $ ");
        }

        de.append("\n");
        de.append("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");   For this code, i am getting the above sonar issue . Please help me resolve the issue

Comment: So which line is causing the `error` Everything looks fine, and runs ok in [ideone](http://ideone.com/cIkZAK), except for the Collection of Strings that we don't know.

Comment: Give the whole stacktrace. Provide [mcve]

Comment: This code does not produce this message. Your question and the error message say `StringBuffer`, but your code uses `StringBuilder`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Please find screenshot i append , where i used the StringBuilder but i get the above error

Comment: You have to rebuild your project or something.

Comment: Please get rid of the irrelevant code and the pointless screenshot; post the real code; and try to make some sense out of your meaningless question. Or lose it. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `StringBuffer` you probably have a `String` you want to append. Use it to determinate the initial size of the buffer.

```
String myStringToAppend = "whatever";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(myStringToAppend);
//append and append
String result = sb.toString();
```

After seeing your error, I suggest cleaning the project. Rightclick on the project and chose `clean project`

Comment: Why you wanna do something like this? Do you see any advantage here using a StringBuffer? Unless something gets append before sb.toString()

Comment: That's what I wrote. Instead of a comment append the String. In java 7 we did this way.

Comment: Yeah if you append something that is fine. Otherwise it is just cause more memory

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne You don't appear to have read the question. There are two `append()` calls in the OP's code, and an unknown number more inside the loop.

Comment: @EJP The code was not published when I put the above comment :D What I meant was that xenteros sample is not a good example for use of StringBuilder/Buffer unless he do some append before sb.toString();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting such error using below code,

package com.test;

public class StringMethods
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StringBuilder de = new StringBuilder(51);
    de.append("=================================\n"); 
    de.append("Selection from Final Module List\n"); 
    de.append("=================================\n"); 
    de.append("\n"); 
    de.append("-------------------------------------------------‌​--------------------‌​---------------\n");

    System.out.println(de.toString());


}
```

}

===

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720833/insufficient-string-buffer-declaration  - we will get error , even if we use default constructor